# USB debugging permission alerts stopped although USB Debugging is enabled on android 4.4.2

Tags: usb-debugging

I was able to connect my android mobile to my computer as I enabled USB debugging from the developer options. I used to receive the USB debugging permission alert and from there I switch from charging to file transfer.

All of a sudden and while my device is having a low space problem, the USB debugging permission alert stopped appear when I connect it to my PC. That means I can not connect him to my PC as I can not give the permission as the default is charging. I tried two different PCs (Ubuntu based, and Windows 10 based) with no luck as well as two different cables. I used another android phone with the same cable and to the same PC and it connects OK.

My mobile has an Android version of 4.4.2 and updates stopped a while ago. 
My other mobile (Android 7.0) is connecting with no problem. I connected several times before from this mobile with no issue.

I tried to restart the mobile and switch off and on the USB debugging option with no luck. I am trying to connect it to my computer to take some backup and free some space.

**Here is the information of my mobile:**

1. Huawei Honor 4C CHM-U1
2. Memory at the current time: 391 MB Free 8 GB total
3. Android version of 4.4.2

Can any body help me how to fix this?

Comment: Just for clarification: Are you only worried that the alert no longer appears – or can you no longer connect that device to a computer at all? In the latter case: have you tried a different cable as well? And does charging still work via the same port?

Comment: I added more clarification to answer your question. I can not connect the mobile unless the notification appeared, and yes I used two different cables, I even used another android mobile with the same cable and it worked fine.

Comment: Ah! You mean the notification about USB *connection* – which you'd then tap and select the connection mode? If it's that, please try the following: With the cable connected, go to *Settings › Storage* and see if there's an option to switch connection mode. Some devices have this setting in *Settings › Development* ("chose USB configuration" or similar item). Let us know if you found something and which action helped (if any).

Answer (score -1):

It was a hardware problem. When I pushed the cable hard into the port, it connected. I will need to fix the port. Thanks for the support.